# increment a number based on condition

Tags: c++, qt

I have a basic question, I have realtime data. I need to count number of times the data value crosses a threshold.

`realtime_data` is a data stream at a rate of 10Hz.

I tried this:

```
 int pCount=0;

    if(realtime_data>0.25)
    {
        ++pCount;
        ui->lbl_peak->setText(QString::number(pCount));
    }
```

But this does increment only one time. Does not count all the occurrences. Can someone show me the right way to do this?

**EDIT**

This is how I call `realtime_data`:

```
void Settings::EventHandler(uint8_t index, DATA_T *sample)
{
    realtimeDataSlot(sample->sensor_value[0]);
}


void Settings::realtimeDataSlot(double realtime_data)
{

// Here I need to check if the data exceeds a threshold value and count those occurrences

    int pCount=0;

   if(realtime_data>0.25)
    {
        ++pCount;
        ui->lbl_peak->setText(QString::number(pCount));
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the values of `realtime_data`?

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop.  Without more information that is just a guess.

Comment: How are you calling this? Every time `realtime_data` change?

Comment: you say "crosses a threshold" but your code only checks if the value is larger than the threshold, ie when the threshold is crossed from below. Please post a [mcve]. It is unclear how this snippet is supposed to continuosly check the value unless this is inside a loop

Comment: When and where do you have this check? How often do you expect this check to happen? Will the values be what you expected? Have you tried to use a debugger and add a breakpoint on the check to see if it happens multiple times, and what the value of `realtime_data` is?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys!. The `realtime_data` is changing continuously at a rate of 10Hz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `pCount` in your `realtimeDataSlot` function which means that everytime the function is called pCount is back to 0. Make pCount a member variable of your class.

Comment: Likely true, but the question is incomplete.

Comment: Can't it just be declared as `static`?

Comment: @Ivan, then the count would be shared between instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

every time the function is called, pcount would be setted to zero.
So pcount would only be zero or one.
Setting pcount as static would solve the problem.

```
void Settings::realtimeDataSlot(double realtime_data)
{

// Here I need to check if the data exceeds a threshold value and count those     occurrences

    static int pCount=0;
    if(realtime_data>0.25)
    {
        ++pCount;
        ui->lbl_peak->setText(QString::number(pCount));
    }
}
```